# How to handle Custom React Event as component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume that we have a reusable button component.
We give an `onClick` prop for the handle `handleClick` event.

```
<Button onClick={(e)=>{doSomething(e)}}/>
```

But also I want to change text property of button when user click.

To illustrate like this:

```
export default class Button extends React.Component{
    static propTypes = {
       onClick:PropTypes.func
    } 

    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text:'Not Clicked the Button'
    } 
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this) 
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({text:'Clicked the Button'})
        this.props.onClick(e)
    };

    render(){
       const {text} = this.state 
       return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{text}</button>
           )
     }
}
```

When trying like this it is getting an error show below:

```
TypeError: onClick is not a function
```

What should be for fix this error.

What is the best way handling events for the reusable components.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to work, there has to be some other flaw in your code not visible. Check out here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/6yyp2mv86k

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code that could replicate the problem. Also, there's a typo, `onCLick`.

Comment: you've got one too many closing braces in your `Button` prop

Comment: @ZohirSalak it seems well.

Comment: You have passed onClick as prop to the Button component which is one of the best ways to do it.

Comment: Oh my so sorry, I better go get my glasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
if there is not default value of prop func it gives an this error.

So at the begining it should consist of `onClick` default value as null.

```
static defaultProps = {
 onClick:null
}
```